# Cursive/Intellij - undefined step_definitions warning

Tags: intellij-idea, clojure, cursive

I am using `lein-cucumber` to write cucumber tests.
My test suit executes without any errors, but my IDE flags these warnings:

- Given cannot be resolved.
- Then cannot be resolved.
- Undefined step reference: ...

[image]
[image]

I have installed the plug-ins: `cursive`, `cucumber` and `gherkin` into Intellij. But these warnings are still shown.

This is my project.clj file:

```
(defproject app version
  :dependencies [
  [org.clojure/clojure "1.8.0"]
  [org.clojure/tools.logging "0.4.0"]
  [org.clojure/tools.cli "0.3.5"]
  [org.clojure/data.json "0.2.6"]
  [clj-http "3.9.1"]
  [mysql/mysql-connector-java "5.1.38"]
  [org.slf4j/slf4j-log4j12 "1.7.25"]
  [log4j/log4j "1.2.17" :exclusions [javax.mail/mail
  javax.jms/jms
  com.sun.jmdk/jmxtools
  com.sun.jmx/jmxri]]
  [metosin/compojure-api "1.1.11"]
  [metosin/ring-swagger "0.24.3"]
  [compojure "1.6.0"]
  [cheshire "5.8.0"]
  [ring "1.6.3"]
  [ring/ring-json "0.4.0"]
  [ring-logger "0.7.7"]
  [environ "1.1.0"]
  [korma "0.4.3"]
  [blackwater "0.0.9"]
  [prismatic/schema "1.1.7"]
  [siili/humanize "0.1.1"]
  [amazonica "0.3.117"]
  [clj-time "0.14.2"]
  [ring-cors "0.1.12"]
  [commons-io "2.0"]
  ]

  :plugins      [
  [lein-ring "0.12.1"]
  [lein-cucumber "1.0.2"]
  [lein-cloverage "1.0.10"]
  [lein-kibit "0.1.6"]
  [lein-cloverage "1.0.10"]
  [lein-try "0.4.3"]
  [nightlight/lein-nightlight "1.0.0"]
  [jonase/eastwood "0.2.3"]
  [cider/cider-nrepl "0.16.0"]
  ]

  :min-lein-version "2.5.3"

  :ring {:handler app.api.handler/app}

  :source-paths ["src"]

  :resource-paths ["resources"]

  :test-paths ["test/unit"
  "test/features"]

  :cucumber-feature-paths ["test/features"]

  :profiles {:uberjar {:aot :all}}
  )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can happen when using a library that defines vars/functions dynamically. Cursive can't discover those definitions because it would require evaluating the code that generates the definitions.

This appears to be the case seeing how [`Given` is defined](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm-clojure/blob/d95fb406b817feaa91e8a6eadf4207b3f1799f3e/clojure/src/main/clojure/cucumber/runtime/clj.clj#L138). I've also seen this with libraries like Amazonica that generate definitions based on AWS SDK.

Comment: Are you saying that this is the expected behaviour? It kind of implies in this [tutorial](https://github.com/gphilipp/bdd-guide-clojure#step-3---edit-the-glue-file-with-cursive) that the warnings should go away when you specify the test-paths, but for me it doesn't :(

Comment: @Freid001 The tutorial says that the fix will get rid of IntelliJ's bad guesses (`javafx.beans.binding.When`), not that it will allow them to be resolved. This is the problem when using macros to define symbols. The IDE can't know what symbols are created using macros.